# Hive INSERT OVERWRITE to Google Storage as LOCAL DIRECTORY not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-cloud-storage, google-hadoop

I use the following Hive Query:

```
hive> INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY "gs:// Google/Storage/Directory/Path/Name" row format delimited fields terminated by ','
select * from <HiveDatabaseName>.<HiveTableName>;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
"Error: Failed with exception Wrong FS:"gs:// Google/Storage/Directory/PathName", expected: file:///
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: what is gs:// ?? here

Comment: gs is Google Storage.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `Local` from your syntax. 
**See the below syntax**

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'gs://Your_Bucket_Path/'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" 
SELECT * FROM YourExistingTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in Hive, including IIRC Hive 1.2.1, where it uses the configured `fs.default.name` or `fs.defaultFS` for its scratchdir even if the table path is in a different filesystem. In your case, it appears you have the out-of-the-box defaults setting `fs.defaultFS` to `file:///`, which is why it says "expected: file:///". On a distributed Hadoop cluster, you might see it say "expected: hdfs://..." instead.

You can fix it within the single hive prompt by overriding `fs.default.name` and `fs.defaultFS`:

```
> set fs.default.name=gs://your-bucket/
> set fs.defaultFS=gs://your-bucket/
```

You may also want to modify those entries inside your `core-site.xml` file to point at your GCS location to make it easier.